# How to open a menu on Key press in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I got a lot of values inside my player class, and I've verified each with a GUI Text, but now I want to arrange them in the screen with a background image and only pop up when the player presses the "C" key in their keyboard, how can I set the children of a canvas parent to be visible/nonvisible by toggling a key? I checked the Add New Event Type option at the bottom but there is no option for Keycodes only mouse options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a MonoBehaviour that stores a list of GameObjects. Give this MonoBehaviour a method Show and a method Hide. In these methods, iterate over all elements in the list and call SetActive on them.

```
public class UICollection : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] elements;
    private bool visible;

    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return visible; }
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        foreach (GameObject item in elements)
        {
            item.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void Hide()
    {
        foreach (GameObject item in elements)
        {
            item.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Just add the component to your player as a reference. Then you can do something like this in your player-class:

```
[SerializeField]
UICollection ui;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        if (ui.Visible)
            ui.Hide();
        else
            ui.Show();
}
```

I hope this is working for you. You may have to use GetComponent<> to get the Object from somewhere, depending on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown(KeyCode.C))
    {            
        var gameObject = GameObject.Find("..."); // The parent game object to toggle
        gameObject.SetActive(false); //true or false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Brackey's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLhj7SfaxSE   @9:29

//goto: Project settings> Input> and create a key (copy an array and rename)
Name it Inventory

then in your Update look for key-presses

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Inventory"))
        {
            inventoryUI.SetActive(!inventoryUI.activeSelf);
        }

    }
```